# npm install odbc fails on OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: macos, node.js, ubuntu

I'm having an issue install the odbc package on both OSX and Ubuntu.

I have unixODBC installed on both machines.

Here is the output of issuing "npm install odbc":

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/odbc
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/odbc

> odbc@0.6.3 preinstall /home/notes/as400/node_modules/odbc
> node-gyp configure build

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 18, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'script_main'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/share/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/notes/as400/node_modules/odbc
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! odbc@0.6.3 preinstall: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the odbc@0.6.3 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the odbc package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls odbc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/share/node/bin/node" "/usr/share/node/bin/npm" "install" "odbc"
npm ERR! cwd /home/notes/as400
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/notes/as400/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**EDIT 03/05/2014**
I installed unixODBC on my Mac using Macports without any issues.  Now when I try "npm install odbc --save", I get the following error about sql.h missing:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/odbc
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/odbc

> odbc@0.6.3 preinstall /Users/patrick/IdeaProjects/XTL/vouchers-paid/node_modules/odbc
> node-gyp configure build

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc.o
In file included from ../src/odbc.cpp:25:
../src/odbc.h:29:10: fatal error: 'sql.h' file not found
#include <sql.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/odbc_bindings/src/odbc.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/patrick/IdeaProjects/XTL/vouchers-paid/node_modules/odbc
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me (OSX 10.10.2)

1. Installing `unixODBC` via MacPorts **did not work**. The port itself 
   installs and automatically updates the include paths and the compiler
   finds `sql.h`. But then the linker fails.
2. Installing `unixodbc` via Homebrew **works**. The include paths are not 
   updated, but this can be fixed, as indicated by the other answers.

For the installation of the `odbc` package you can use the following shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SRC_ODBC=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2_1/include
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:$SRC_ODBC
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:$SRC_ODBC
npm install odbc
```

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Mojave. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As stated on npmjs.org there are additional binaries that need to be installed:

```
> on Ubuntu/Debian sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
> on OSX using macports.org sudo port unixODBC
```

for more info: https://www.npmjs.org/package/odbc

Comment: Pretty sure I have all the deps on Ubuntu.  I remember installing unixodbc-dev.  As for OSX, I downloaded unixodbc from unixodbc.org and built from source. Would that not work properly the with the odbc package?

Comment: I've configured that both unixodbc and unixodbc-dev are installed on my Ubuntu server.

Comment: After successfully installing unixODBC using Macports, I get a new error about sql.h missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo port unixODBC
```

is also wrong.

```
sudo port install unixodbc
```

is right.

Port install the lib and header files in other directories /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib. To use them you have to told npm or the environment about. 
But no idea how. May someone more experienced.

Or you use homebrew:

```
brew install unixodbc
```

That will work.

Comment: $ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include:/opt/local/lib
$ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include:/opt/local/lib
$ npm install odbc
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

Answer (score 0):

After installing using
    sudo port install unixodbc

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Where_You_Installed/ibm/dsdriver/include
$ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Where_You_Installed/ibm/dsdriver/include
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Then run

```
npm install ibm_db
```